# Filter an arraylist to use in an image adapter

Tags: android, image, listview, filter, adapter

So I have an `ImageAdapter` that I need to use in 2 `ListView` of 2 different layouts.I use it for the first, and then want to filter the array, put those values in another array that i use for the second listview.

My Image Adapter

```
package com.weinco.list;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.weinco.R;
import com.weinco.fragments.StandorteFragment;
import com.weinco.webservice.entity.Standort;

import com.weinco.webservice.entity.Standorts;

public class LocationMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private AQuery aQuery;
private Standorts standorts;
private Standort standort;
private StandorteFragment standorteFragment;

public LocationMenuAdapter(StandorteFragment standorteFragment, Standorts standorts) {

    this.standorteFragment = standorteFragment;
    this.standorts = standorts;
    this.aQuery = standorteFragment.aQuery;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(standorteFragment.getActivity());

}

public int getCount() {
    return standorts.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public Standort getStandort(int i) {
    return standorts.get(i);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ListContent holder = null;

    Standort standort = getStandort(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewinflate, null);

        holder = new ListContent();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ListContent) convertView.getTag();

    }


        holder.text.setText(standort.Name);

    return convertView;
}

class ListContent {
    TextView text;

}
}
```

The functions that i use

```
 loadLocationMenuList();
loadBussinessLunchLoc();



private void loadBussinessLunchLoc() {
  ServiceProxy.createWebServiceTask(getActivity(), new RemoteCallListener() {

   @Override
   public void onRemoteCallError(String response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onRemoteCallComplete(Object response) {
    Log.d("debug", "response is = " + response + "\t" + response.getClass());
    Standorts standorts = (Standorts) response;
    for(Standort standort : standorts)
      {
        if(standort.BusinessLunch==true){
           filteredstandorts.add(standort);
        }

      }

    locationMenuAdapter = new LocationMenuAdapter(StandorteFragment.this, filteredstandorts);
    menuItemListLoc2page.setAdapter(locationMenuAdapter);

   }

   @Override
   public void onNoInternetError() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onNoAccess() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  }, true).invokeGetStandorte();
 }

 private void loadLocationMenuList() {
  ServiceProxy.createWebServiceTask(getActivity(), new RemoteCallListener() {

   @Override
   public void onRemoteCallError(String response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onRemoteCallComplete(Object response) {
    Log.d("debug", "response is = " + response + "\t" + response.getClass());
    Standorts standorts = (Standorts) response;

    locationMenuAdapter = new LocationMenuAdapter(StandorteFragment.this, standorts);
    menuItemListLoc.setAdapter(locationMenuAdapter);

   }

   @Override
   public void onNoInternetError() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onNoAccess() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  }, true).invokeGetStandorte();
 }
```

I get the next LogCat Log:

```
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.weinco.list.LocationMenuAdapter.getCount(LocationMenuAdapter.java:37)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:454)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.weinco.fragments.StandorteFragment$10.onRemoteCallComplete(StandorteFragment.java:283)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.weinco.webservice.CallWebServiceTask.onPostExecute(CallWebServiceTask.java:543)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.weinco.webservice.CallWebServiceTask.onPostExecute(CallWebServiceTask.java:1)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3744)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-01 11:06:04.171: E/AndroidRuntime(16286):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no ideea what i have to do to correct this, i searched the net for some filters, but what i found was more java than android, and i could really understand what they were doing.

Comment: You should add your logcat output so we can get the origin of the force close.

Comment: no more Force Close, so LogCat won't help. I get the second list with the same number of lines, but instead of having streets, all the lines just say "False"

Comment: How exactly do you filter the values, looking at your code you're using basically the same code?

Comment: ok, i got it, i have to filter the arraylist "standorts" and then only run the second image adapter. Just have to learn to do that now :p

Comment: `standorts` in the adapter(a.k.a `filteredstandorts` by the code in `onRemoteCallComplete`) is `null` and when the `getCount` method is called a `NullPointerException` is thrown(my guess is that you don't initialize `filteredstandorts` and as `standort.BusinessLunch` is false you only see the exception in the adapter). Nobody can help you if you don't put some details regarding what type of data you have(like the `Standorts`, `Standort` class), how do you plan to sort it etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the documentation they told me to make BusinessLunch a boolean, but from the webservice call they were sending me an integer with the value of 0 or 1. That's why it didn't show anything when it was compiled.